# Calculated Column and File Name 'Title' Field

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, calculated-column, modern-experience, flow

I uploaded more the 2000 images files to an SP document library.

When I checked the 'See Details' under the file name property options, I noticed the actual name of the file appears in the "Name" field, but not the "Title" field. Why did SP add the name one place and not the other; especially if the content of "Title" is what an SP calculated column defaults to for calculations; which is my issue.

I now want to create a calculated column but the formula doesn't work because there is no data in "Title", and "Title" is the only column name option given to me when creating the calculated column.

The question also being asked, "why can't I see/access 'Name' column" in the column options when creating the calculated column? That would fix everything.

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: This is the default behavior in SharePoint. You can populate the file name in Title using Power automate flow on file creation/updation.

Comment: What about those already in the Library? How is this accomplished retroactively?

Comment: For existing items you can use PowerShell/REST API script to update as a one time activity. Or you can write a temporary flow to run on all items in loop and update title field.

Comment: You have an example. You assume level of expertise that doesn't exist. Do I start with a "Get Item", or "Get Items", "Update Item". A little help would be greatly appreciated. Also, the Library will be used to upload all new images from PS (flow already exists). How will what you propose impact those images and these new columns?

Comment: Are you uploading images to SharePoint using power automate flow? If this is what you are saying then you can update the Title field at the time of file upload (not sure maybe you will need extra action like update item based on how you have configured your flow).

Comment: Yep; you're right. I should be able to add up 'Title' with all other columns. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad it helped you. I have written it as an answer below and added screenshot for your reference. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior in SharePoint. When you upload the file to document library, file name will be stored in Name field and not Title.

**Workaround**:

You can populate the file name in Title field using Power automate flow on file creation/updation.

You can implement flow something like below:

[image]

Comment: ...and, what about the effort to put content in the Title of those 'already' uploaded; that Power Shell (which I've never tried), REST/API part? Ya got anything for that? Thanks!